# Line chart in D3.js is not drawing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I drew a linechart using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940). Here I did some changes.I put some divs with data inside body tag. Then I set time as the   x-axis and true/false value for y-axis. I got time values for dataset using regular experssion. This will be easy to understand by looking at following code. When there were the commented dataset(in this code), it is drown nicely,But after the changes it does not working? Please help me to identify the error that I have done.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//First I test this code with this data set and It worked!!!
/*var dataset = [   
  {x: '2013-03-12 08:00:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 08:20:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 08:29:04', y: false},
  {x: '2013-03-12 09:30:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 09:45:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 09:55:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 10:01:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 10:09:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 10:25:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 11:37:04', y: false},
  {x: '2013-03-12 12:43:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 12:59:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 13:10:04', y: true},
  {x: '2013-03-12 13:09:04', y: true},    
  
];*/
    

    
/******newest adding code for get data ********/
var dataset = [];
 var mainRootID = 1;
var listID,listID_a; 
var goThruoughBranch = 1;
var testlistID,testlistID_a;  
var findbranch,dataStatement; 
var testDate;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    listID = mainRootID + '_' + goThruoughBranch;
    listID_a = mainRootID + '_' + goThruoughBranch+'_a';
    testlistID= document.getElementById(listID);
    
    if(testlistID.childNodes[0].id=="T"){
        //alert('come inside to the if : T occur');
        testlistID_a = document.getElementById(listID_a);
        dataStatement = testlistID_a.innerHTML;
        //alert(dataStatement);
        testDate = dateCatcher(dataStatement);
        //alert(testDate);
        
         dataset.push({
          x: parseDate(testDate),
          y: true,
          testcase: 'TestSuite:'+mainRootID+'   test:'+listID
        });
        //drowLineChart();
    }else if(testlistID.childNodes[0].id=="F") {
         //alert('come inside to the else if: F occur');
        testlistID_a = document.getElementById(listID_a);
        dataStatement = testlistID_a.innerHTML;
         //alert(dataStatement);
        testDate = dateCatcher(dataStatement);
        
        
        
         dataset.push({
          x: parseDate(testDate),
          y: false,
          testcase: 'TestSuite:'+mainRootID+'   test:'+listID
        });
       // drowLineChart();
        //setDotInLineChart();
    }else{
        //alert('come inside to the else: start occur');    
    }
    
    goThruoughBranch++;
    
    if(goThruoughBranch==13){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
   // alert('dataset.length'+dataset.length);
}, 100);
    
//Gives the date part from the whole statement    
function dateCatcher(statement){

    var date_finder =/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
    var datePart = statement.match(date_finder);
    datePart[2] -= 1;
    var UtcDate = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(this, datePart.slice(1)));
    
    //var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = UtcDate.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = UtcDate.getUTCDate();
    var year = UtcDate.getUTCFullYear();
    var hours = UtcDate.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = UtcDate.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = UtcDate.getUTCSeconds();
    
var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    
    return newdate;
}        
/**********************************************************/    
    
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;    
  
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);    
    
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range([0,height]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));
 
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);
    
 dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x = parseDate(d.x);
    });    
    
xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.x; }));    
yScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {return d.y;} ));        


var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select(".chart3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
  .axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }

  .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Line Chart</title>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="ul_11">
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_1"><li id="start"><a id="1_1_a"> 2015-01-02 11:47:50 Test 11 1 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_2"><li id="T"><a id="1_2_a"> 2015-01-02 11:50:57 Test 11 1 Passed</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_3"><li id="start"><a id="1_3_a"> 2015-01-02 11:57:20 Test 11 2 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_4"><li id="T"><a id="1_4_a"> 2015-01-02 12:10:02 Test 11 2 Passed</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_5"><li id="start"><a id="1_5_a"> 2015-01-02 12:15:14 Test 11 3 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_6"><li id="F"><a id="1_6_a"> 2015-01-02 12:20:24 Test 11 3 Failed</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_7"><li id="start"><a id="1_7_a"> 2015-01-02 12:35:12 Test 11 4 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_8"><li id="F"><a id="1_8_a"> 2015-01-02 12:46:20 Test 11 4 Failed</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_9"><li id="start"><a id="1_9_a"> 2015-01-02 11:57:10 Test 11 5 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_10"><li id="T"><a id="1_10_a">2015-01-02 12:00:00 Test 11 5 Passed</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_11"><li id="start"><a id="1_11_a">2015-01-02 12:12:20 Test 11 6 Started</a></li></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_12"><li id="F"><a id="1_12_a">2015-01-02 12:20:24 Test 11 6 Failed</a></li></div>     
</ul>    
    
<div class="chart3"></div>      
    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Do you have an error?

Comment: @Marc : No, there is no errors.It shows tat the array is also not empty.

Comment: Is your regular expression ok? Does it return the expected data values? Do a simple write to check it,. If it doesn't this is completely a problem related to extracting the data from whatever your source.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga: my regular expression returns expected data value properly.There isn't matter in regEx.

Comment: Did u checked printing the var dataset after pushing the values?

Answer (score 1):

First, why is your data parsing wrapped in a `setInterval` (was this some sort of attempt at looping?).  Your parsing will start after you've drawn your graph (and `dataset` will be an empty array).  Cleaning it up (your current parsing is way broken), you can simplify:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse,
  dataset = [],
  mainRootID = 1;

// select all lis that have an id or T or F
d3.selectAll('li#T,li#F').each(function() {

  // self will be d3 selector with the li
  var self = d3.select(this),
    // textData is the contents of the a tag
    textData = self.select('a').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(" "),
    // this is the id of lis parent div
    listID = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('id');

  dataset.push({
    x: parseDate(textData[0] + " " + textData[1]), // parse to date
    y: self.attr("id") === "T", // figure out if its t or f
    testcase: 'TestSuite:' + mainRootID + ' test:' + listID
  });

});

// sort the data
dataset.sort(function(d1,d2){
  return d1.x < d2.x;
})
```

After that is straightened out, the graph is back.

Full working code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Line Chart</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .tick text {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .tick line {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="ul_11">
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_1">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_1_a"> 2015-01-02 11:47:50 Test 11 1 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_2">
      <li id="T">
        <a id="1_2_a"> 2015-01-02 11:50:57 Test 11 1 Passed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_3">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_3_a"> 2015-01-02 11:57:20 Test 11 2 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_4">
      <li id="T">
        <a id="1_4_a"> 2015-01-02 12:10:02 Test 11 2 Passed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_5">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_5_a"> 2015-01-02 12:15:14 Test 11 3 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_6">
      <li id="F">
        <a id="1_6_a"> 2015-01-02 12:20:24 Test 11 3 Failed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_7">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_7_a"> 2015-01-02 12:35:12 Test 11 4 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_8">
      <li id="F">
        <a id="1_8_a"> 2015-01-02 12:46:20 Test 11 4 Failed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_9">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_9_a"> 2015-01-02 11:57:10 Test 11 5 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_10">
      <li id="T">
        <a id="1_10_a">2015-01-02 12:00:00 Test 11 5 Passed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_11">
      <li id="start">
        <a id="1_11_a">2015-01-02 12:12:20 Test 11 6 Started</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" id="1_12">
      <li id="F">
        <a id="1_12_a">2015-01-02 12:20:24 Test 11 6 Failed</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <div class="chart3"></div>

  <script>
  
    /* parse data */
  
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse,
      dataset = [],
      mainRootID = 1;

    d3.selectAll('li#T,li#F').each(function() {

      var self = d3.select(this),
        textData = self.select('a').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(" "),
        listID = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('id');

      dataset.push({
        x: parseDate(textData[0] + " " + textData[1]),
        y: self.attr("id") === "T",
        testcase: 'TestSuite:' + mainRootID + ' test:' + listID
      });
      
    });
    
    // sort the data
    dataset.sort(function(d1,d2){
      return d1.x < d2.x;
    })
    
    /* plot data */

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 100
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range([0, height]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .innerTickSize(-height)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(10)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .innerTickSize(-width)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(10);

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));

    yScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    }));

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
      });

    var svg = d3.select(".chart3").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

    svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used setInterval function because I need to update the line chart inside a  time period. Thanks for your code.... Can I do this inside a setInterval function? Then each time, inside the function, it updates the array and show the graph corresponding to it. Is it the way for doing this task or is there any easiest way for it?

Comment: @DesiDelite, how does the data inside your `uls` update?  The way it looks now, you'd just re-parse the same data over and over...

Comment: Is there any  possible method to do this task inside a setInterval function?